# Compare columns of 2 dataframes with a combination of index and row value

Tags: python, pandas

There are quite a few similar questions out there, but I am not sure if there is one that tackles both index and row values. (relevant to binary classification df)

So what I am trying to do is compare the columns with the same name to have the same values and index. If not, simply return an error.

Let's say DataFrame `df` has columns `a`, `b` and `c` and `df_orginal` has columns from `a` to `z`.

How can we first find the columns that have the same name between those 2 DataFrames, and then check the contents of those columns such that they match row by row in value and index between `a`, `b` and `c` from `df` and `df_orginal`

The contents of all the columns are numerical, that's why I want to compare the combination of index and values

Demo:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   a  b  c  
0  0  1  2  
1  1  2  0  
2  0  1  0  
3  1  1  0  
4  3  1  0  

In [3]: df_orginal
Out[3]:
   a  b c d e f g ......
0  4  3 1 1 0 0 0
1  3  1 2 1 1 2 1
2  1  2 1 1 1 2 1
3  3  4 1 1 1 2 1
4  0  3 0 0 1 1 1
```

In the above example, for those columns that have the same column name, compare the combination of index and value and flag an error if the combination of index and value is not correct

Comment: Please provide some data for better understanding.

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ShivamGaur please check

Comment: Example output? Just df with 'Error' where there is no match? Are your indexes always consecutive, starting at 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
common_cols = df.columns.intersection(df_original.columns)

for col in common_cols:

    df1_ind_val_pair = df[col].index.astype(str) + ' ' + df[col].astype(str)
    df2_ind_val_pair = df_original[col].index.astype(str) + ' ' + df_original[col].astype(str)

    if any(df1_ind_val_pair != df2_ind_val_pair):
        print('Found one or more unequal (index, value) pairs in col {}'.format(col))
```

Comment: this looks great but I think instead of comparing the indexes by their own and the values by their own, they should compare both indexes and values at the same time

Comment: guar as in it compares the combination of both

Comment: So, for each column, you would like compare the (index, value) pairs from `df` to (index, value) pairs from `df_original`, and print the column name if **there is even one pair** that is not equal right?

Comment: incredible! Thank you

Comment: Indexes behave like ordered sets so they have most of the methods defined on sets as well. You can just use `df.columns.intersection`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

Use [**`pd.DataFrame.align`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) with a join method of `inner`.  Then pass the resulting `tuple` unpacked to `pd.DataFrame.eq`

```
pd.DataFrame.eq(*df.align(dfo, 'inner'))

       a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
4  False  False   True
```

To see rows that have all columns `True`, filter with this mask:

```
pd.DataFrame.eq(*df.align(dfo, 'inner')).all(1)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

with the sample data however, the result will be empty

```
df[pd.DataFrame.eq(*df.align(dfo, 'inner')).all(1)]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

---

Same answer but with clearer code

```
def eq(d1, d2):
    d1, d2 = d1.align(d2, 'inner')
    return d1 == d2

eq(df, dfo)

       a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
4  False  False   True
```

Comment: yes, this also works, but for a huge table 5mil x 5mil it is almost impossible to check everything. Can it print the position of those that are not equal ?

Comment: Of course, I can't imagine you actually want to print every failure.  But still, we could.  What do you actually want to do?  Are you logging these?  Do you want the ordinal positions (index and columns) or the labels?  You can clear this up by showing the output you expect.

Comment: it would just print if there is false or not. Not actually every single one. But rather if any exists